# Python equivalent to Matlab [a,b] = sort(y)

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

I am pretty new to the Python language and want to know how to the following

```
(1)  y = [some vector]
(2)  z = [some other vector]
(3)  [ynew,indx] = sort(y)
(4)  znew = z(indx)
```

I can do lines 1,2 and 4 but line 3 is giving me fits.  Any suggestions.  What I am looking for is not a user written function but something intrinsic to the language itself.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using NumPy for line 3, assuming `y` is a row vector, otherwise `axis=0` is needed:

```
ynew=y.sort(axis=1)
indx=y.argsort(axis=1)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a command for finding the indices of an array.  Thanks

Comment: I am getting None when sorting this list, what could be a reason?  `m = [[11, -12, 4, 8],
      [6, -9,8,0], 
      [2, 3, 11, -2],
      [1, 1, 9, 3]]
ynew=np.array(m).sort(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the following form, and the solution provided didn't work for me. I found a solution that work for me and I thought I could share it here in case anyone has the same problem:

My goal was to sort x in ascending number and move the indices of y in the same manner

```
x = np.array([00, 44, 22, 33, 11]) # create an array to sort
y = np.array([00, 11, 22, 33, 44]) # another array where you want to move index in the same way you did x
x_sorted = x[x.argsort()] # x sorted in ascending number
y_sorted = y[x.argsort()] # y sorted
```

The difference is that you don't store the original index position but, in my case, it wasn't a problem since I did that to modify multiple array following one. Thus, by using x.argsort(), it already gives where index have to be moved and, I think, will achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

y = [1,3,2]
z = [3,2,1]
indx = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(y), key=lambda x:x[1])]
print(indx)

#convert z to numpy array in order to use np.ix_ function
z = np.asarray(z)

znew = z[np.ix_(indx)]
print(znew)
```

Results:

```
#the indx is
[0, 2, 1]

#the znew is
array([3, 1, 2])
```